# Filter array, then select an element randomly based on weights, without allocation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am wondering if this is possible, say I have an array of struct with following data:

```
struct Data {
  Prop = 25
  Weight = 12
}
```

Now imagine I want to find a random element from the array, with following rules:

1. Filter the array by `Prop` value.
2. Then randomly select an element, using the `Weight` as bias.

It's trivial to create a temporal list and then randomly select an element from it.

**But we ultimately just want 1 element from the array, is there some clever trick to avoid heap alloc?**

Comment: Addendum: as I have full control of the data structure, would also accept answers that suggest a different struct that enable us to achieve the same result without alloc. But it should be Array of struct or Struct of array to make good use CPU cache.

Answer (score -1):

not sure how to pick out the biased random element from the collection, but if you problem is just not creating a temporal list you can easily use LINQ to accomplish that:

```
IEnumerable<Data> myData; // assuming your data is in here
var randomElement = myData.Where(d => d.Prop > 10) //or some other filter
.Single(d => {/*put your code to select the biased element here*/})
```